# After WPF Polygon binding, the graphics remain unchanged

Tags: wpf

I used to assign directly to the set of points, the graphics can be displayed properly, and later found that the performance of doing that is very poor, I thought of using the binding method to do it.

After WPF Polygon binding, the set of points has changed, but the graphics have not changed.

**xaml code**

```
<Canvas Background="Black" Name="map">
            <Polygon Name="pl" Points="{Binding sendPoints,Mode=TwoWay}"></Polygon>
        </Canvas>
```

**backend code**

```
     DrawLinesClass drawLinesClass = new DrawLinesClass();
     pl.DataContext = drawLinesClass;//bind
     pl.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
     pl.StrokeThickness = 2;

 Thread td = new Thread(() =>
            {
                double index = 0,sum=0;
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    if (isRun)
                    {
                        sum+=0.01;
                        pl.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            if (sum * 2 >= map.ActualHeight - 40)
                            {
                                sum = 0;
                                index += 1;
                                //drawLinesClass.sendPoints.Clear();
                            }
                            drawLinesClass.sendPoints.Add(new Point(index * sum, sum * 2));

                            //pl.Points = drawLinesClass.sendPoints;//no bind

                        }));
                    }
                }
            });
            td.IsBackground = true;
            td.Start();
```

**bind model**

```
 public class DrawLinesClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private PointCollection _sendPointsList;

        public PointCollection sendPoints
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sendPointsList == null) _sendPointsList = new PointCollection();
                return _sendPointsList;
            }
            set
            {
                //this._sendPointsList = new PointCollection();
                this._sendPointsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("sendPoints");
            }
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

Now the set of binding points has changed, I hope the graphics can change automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Binding

```
Points="{Binding sendPoints}"
```

where (`Mode=TwoWay` was pointless) only updates its target property `Points` if you assign a new value to its source property `sendPoints`. Just adding points to the existing `sendPoints` collection as in

```
drawLinesClass.sendPoints.Add(new Point(index * sum, sum * 2));
```

won't make the Binding update.

In other scenarios like binding the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl you would simply use an ObservableCollection for the source property. However, this won't work here. You really have to create a new `PointCollection` whenever you add a point.

---

Besides that, better use a `DispatcherTimer` instead of a `Thread` with `Sleep` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
double index = 0,sum=0;

var timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)
};
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    sum += 0.01;
    if (sum * 2 >= map.ActualHeight - 40)
    {
        sum = 0;
        index += 1;
    }
    var points = new PointCollection(drawLinesClass.sendPoints);
    points.Add(new Point(index * sum, sum * 2));
    drawLinesClass.sendPoints = points;
};
timer.Start();
```

To stop the the timer, just call

```
timer.Stop();
```

Also better write

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

---

As a final remark, the Bindings in your view should usually use a common view model, and hence a common `DataContext` that is assigned at the `MainWindow` instance. When you explicitly set a Polyline's `DataContext` in code behind like

```
pl.DataContext = drawLinesClass;
```

it is questionably why you would at all *bind* the Polylines's `Points` property. Instead of Binding and setting the DataContext, you could as well simply write

```
pl.Points = drawLinesClass.sendPoints;
```

and thus even avoid the need for implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. You would also avoid the need for creating a new PointsCollection on each update, because

```
drawLinesClass.sendPoints.Add(new Point(index * sum, sum * 2))
```

will now magically work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I refer to your code and can update the graphics properly. I find that when I update 10,000 points at a time, the CPU usage is very high by 20%.